# Wrong colours when converting TIFF image to PNG in ImageMagick

Tags: colors, imagemagick, tiff

I'm working on a PHP script that automatically converts TIFF images to PNG files.

For that purpose, I use ImageMagick:

```
$ convert a.tif a.png
```

It works to some degree, however, the colours are very acute and deviant from the way they are pictured on my PC. To illustrate the problem, please have a look at the [enclosed files](http://cvdb.de/sonstiges/tiff/), the include:

- The Windows Live Foto Gallery output (that's pretty much how I want it to be)
- The ImageMagick output (the mess I end up with)
- The original TIFF file

Has anyone an idea whether, and if so how, I can alter the ImageMagick colour interpretation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Imagemagick seems to be interpreting the image as sRGB, and the actual colorspace info is embedded in a XMP metadata tag as an ICC profile, which it ignores.  I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Wow, that did the trick. I was able to download the ISO 12647-2:2004 ICC profile at eci.org and convert it to eciRGB (also to be found at eci.org). The result is even better than in Windows: http://cvdb.de/sonstiges/tiff/c.png

    $ convert -geometry 300 -profile ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc -profile eciRGB_v2.icc a.tif c.png

did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright,

thanks to ergosys, the problem was easily solved: I needed to apply ICC colour profiles.
The XMP declared ISO 12647-2:2004, which was to be found at http://eci.org.

```
$ convert -profile ISOcoated_v2_eci.icc -profile eciRGB_v2.icc a.tif c.png
```

Answer (score 1):

When converting from a CMYK color space to an RGB color space, as you do when going from tiff to png, you have to convert the color spaces along with the image.  Try:

```
convert -colorspace rgb a.tif a.png
```

I ran this locally and get a better result from this than from the command line in your question, but my color vision sucks, so I can't guarantee that this is what you were after.  =]  Hope it gets you on the right track, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the output doesn't change visibly.
I will continue to search for the color space issue, though.
http://cvdb.de/sonstiges/tiff/b.png